# Display MySQL query results in HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I am trying to display some query results from MySQL in a HTML table. I have tried to display the table in a new php page, which works fine. My problem is that I can't seem to find a way to display the table in the same html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="relative.css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>

<div class="cabecera">
    <h1> GENUS </h1>
</div>

<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="profile.html">Perfil</a></li>
    <li><a href="member.html">Nuevo pariente</a></li>   
    <li><a href="relative.html" class="relative">Parientes registrados</a></li>
</ul>

<?php

 require_once 'connectbd.php';
 $conn = connectbd();


session_start();
$escritor = $_SESSION["escritor"];

$sql="SELECT * FROM Pariente WHERE escritor_ID='$escritor' ";

$result= mysql_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysql_error($conn));
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0) die("No hay registros para mostrar");

echo '<table border=1 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0>';

 echo '<tr>
     <th colspan=5> Agenda personal </th>
   <tr>
     <th> ID </th><th> Nombre </th><th> Primer Apellido </th>
  </tr>';

while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

echo'<tr><td>'.$res['nombre'].'</td><td>'.$res['primer_apellido'].'</td><td>'.$res['segundo_apellido'].'</td></tr>';

}
echo '</table>';


?>

<a href="logout.php"><input type="button" value="Cerrar sesión" /></a>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my connectbd.php code:

```
<?php

class DB_Connect {

// constructor
function __construct() {

}

// destructor
function __destruct() {
    // $this->close();
}

// Connecting to database
public function connect() {
    require_once 'config.php';
    // connecting to mysql
    $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    // selecting database
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

    // return database handler
    return $con;
}

// Closing database connection
public function close() {
    mysql_close();
}

}

?>
```

EDIT: This is the table displayed:

[image]

Comment: You're getting any errors??

Comment: That html code is stored in a html file? Or a php file?

Comment: I added a snapshot of the table displayed. @nanocv I have stored the html in a html file

Comment: Your table's header row is malformed. You're opening a `<tr>` after _Agenda personal_ without closing the first one. Also, viewing your errors, looks like your file doesn't have `.php` extension but `.html`.

Comment: @IreneHerrera, always you want to execute php, you have to place it into a `.php` file, even when it starts with html code. Regards from Málaga ;)

Comment: Thank you @nanocv, how silly of me!